# Toolbar won't scroll under transparent statusbar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, statusbar, transparent, android-toolbar

I'd like the toolbar(actionbar) to hide completely when scrolling down. On launching the activity or scrolling back up the toolbar should be visible and the statusbar light grey.

1. start as [ statusbar | toolbar | content ]
2. scrolling down [ co-(statusbar)-ntent ]
3. scrolling up [ statusbar | toolbar | content ]

currently:

1. on startup / boot
   [image: startup / boot]
2. scrolled content down
   [image: Scrolled content down]
3. scrolled content up
   [image: Scrolled content up]

activity_layout.xml

```xml
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/background_white"
tools:context="com.conevoud.captjeluigi.ui.activities.GalleryActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <include layout="@layout/toolbar" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

<include layout="@layout/drawer_left" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

toolbar.xml

```xml
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="?popup_theme"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
</merge>
```

styles:

```xml
    <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>

    <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
```

thank you for reading this.

Comment: Any luck fixing this?

Comment: I found solution, someone still wants to know?

Comment: yes, please. @ThirdMartian

Comment: @Nominalista can you help me pls? I have the same problem :/

Answer (score 0):

I had a sinular problem before, try setting `android:fitsSystemWindows=”true”` in your AppBarLayout.

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_frame"
    android:fitsSystemWindows=”true”
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="?popup_theme"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar problem. Mine was solved.

1. Added `android:fitsSystemWindows="true" to the`AppBarLayout.
2. Added`app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"` for Toolbar

Below is the layout I had.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".HomeActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/id_tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/id_viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

it's looks like the only options is - get rid of

```
<item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
```

property